# Is Arduino Due capable of transmitting video through internet?

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, camera

Is Arduino Due capable of interfacing with a IP camera or any other webcams and transmit the video over the internet to a remote location through Ethernet?

Comment: The "urgency" stated is *your* problem, not that of those contributors here who volunteer their time, effort and knowledge to help people asking questions. Editing out such irrelevant text from the question.

Comment: If you already have an IP camera, what do you need the Due for when transmitting the video signal over Ethernet?

Comment: As far as internet speed goes, try the Taijiuino Due. it has a more direct interface with the wiznet chip, which will speed things up, compared to being limited by the spi transfer speed with the wiznet chip. This method makes use of an internet port that is built into the main processor of the due.

Answer (score 1):

Since the question does not specify any image processing requirement, nor is there a specific frame rate or image resolution specified, the answer is yes: Digital video is merely data, and a microcontroller can transmit data.

If you add an Ethernet module or "shield" to the Arduino Due, configure the module or shield to interface with your Ethernet LAN and thence the Internet, and write or obtain the appropriate software libraries to interface with the webcam of interest, the video stream can certainly be transferred over the Internet.

Comment: It's probably a good idea to note that you will very likely **not** get anything close to 30 FPS at a decent resolution. A few frames-second should be doable with a due, though. A lot depends on your ethernet PHY.

Comment: @ConnorWolf Haha that's why I began with the mention of no frame rate or resolution being specified. However, there are actually projects out there using the Due for full frame rate video processing: That's a pretty fast ARM chip in that board. Available frame buffer RAM is the challenge, more than processing or data transfer.

Comment: Thanks........
I am planning to implement an embedded server using Arduino Due Which needs to control a Robotic Arm. The IP camera is needed to monitor the Robotic Arm.
The robotic arm needs to be controlled from a remote location far away, so need to send live videos to the remote location.

Comment: @Anindo - Yes. Another issue is probably going to be the PHY. If the etnernet PHY used is a Wiznet or one of the microchip ENC28J60 devices, there will be serious additional bottlenecks in the ethernet interface as well.

Comment: @ConnorWolf Agreed: As they write in requirements specifications, "outside current scope".